# Error: Not unique table/alias while joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need both the previous class and current class details. I am using `fk`'s for better performance. Since the `fkcurrentClassId` & `fkpreviousClassId` are trying to get the info of same column `studentClass` . may be this is causing the error can someone helpme out with this.

error: **`Not unique table/alias`**

MyQuery:

```
         Select `fkStudentId`,`fkcurrentClassId`,`fkpreviousClassId`,`studentClass` 

            from
               dbStudents`.`tbStudentClass`
            join
              `dbStudents`.`tbStudentClass`
            on 
              `tbClass`.`pkClassId` = `tbStudentClass`.`fkcurrentClassId`
            join 
              `dbStudents`.`tbStudentClass`
            on
              `tbClass`.`pkClassId` = `tbStudentClass`.`fkpreviousClassId`
```

Comment: What is the error? Also update some sample data and expected output

Comment: You can't join a table onto itself

Comment: @Dan: Oh yes, you can.

Comment: This question has no apparent relationship to either PHP or phpMyAdmin so I've removed those tags.

Comment: @stickybit no, thats what causing this error, test it out yourself you will see

Comment: @Dan: You can join a table with itself as often as you like (well, you may hit some limit in query text length or operation count at some point, far far somewhere in the desert). That you'd then have to use proper aliases to resolve ambiguities is another story. Maybe that is what you actually mean? And what I suspect is the error the OP is getting.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You have to use unique aliases to address a table's column, if the table appears more than once in the `FROM` clause (including any `JOIN`s). Otherwise the reference is ambiguous and the DBMS can't tell what you wanted.

As you didn't post the DDL (nor DML) for your table(s) nor exactly, what you want to do there, I have the same problem as the DBMS and don't know which is what in your query. So I can only give you an unrelated example. You'll have to figure out what you want to be from what joined table in your query yourself and alias it accordingly.

```
SELECT a1.a,
       a2.a,
       a3.a,
       a4.a,
       a5.a,
       a1.i,
       a2.i,
       a3.i,
       a4.i,
       a5.i
       FROM a a1
            INNER JOIN a a2
                       ON a2.i = a1.i
            INNER JOIN a a3
                       ON a3.i = a2.i
            INNER JOIN a a4
                       ON a4.i = a3.i
            INNER JOIN a a5
                       ON a5.i = a4.i;
```

Note the `a1` to `a5` aliases for `a`.

Use [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24c796/1/0) to see it in action.